# How to allow js to be put in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a HTML file and am wondering how I would be able to put it into HTML without an JS file being needed

Comment: You are trying to include an HTML file within another HTML file? Do you want an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Hey, Fellafella, as you can see you are receiving random answers that might not really solve the problem you have. That is because your question is "poorly written". Try to add more details and perhaps more context around the issue you are having. Help us help you better :)

Comment: May you give us more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 Imports, we can now use the element to load one HTML file into another.

```
<link href="extern.html" rel="import" />
```

Accessing Contents of the Import File
Content from the imported document will be loaded, but not displayed. All the texts, images and other media will not be visible as they are not part of the DOM tree of the parent document. You can still access them via JavaScript, though.

```
var extern = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].import;
```

Our example assumes that the first "link" element loads an HTML file. Using the JavaScript property "import" we write the complete tree structure of the imported file to a variable. From there we are able to access the individual nodes via JavaScript.

```
var getPTag= extern.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
```

From here we can access and read all nodes using the common JavaScript methods such as "getElementsByTagName()". Now we are able to add them comfortably to the DOM tree of the parent document. In a more radical approach we could as well replace the "body" element completely with the contents of the imported file.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].replaceChild(extern.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done this work using the help of custom JavaScript.

Lets suppose you have an HTML file named: **file1.html**

& you want to add the content of **file1.html** in **home.html** file when home.html opens, It should also show the content from **file.html** file.

For this do the following.

Create a file named:**file1.html** & add the following code.

```
<h1>This is Content from file1.html</h1>
```

Create another file named:**home.html** & add the following code.

```
<script>
function includeHTML()
{
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++)
    {
        elmnt = z[i];
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file)
        {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4)
                {
                    if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
                    if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
                    elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                    includeHTML();
                }
            }      
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            return;
        }
    }
};
</script>
<h1>This is Content from Home1.html.</h1>
<div w3-include-html="file1.html"></div> 
<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be iframe you are looking for? An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp